# Understanding the VMware ESXi limitations of the free Version

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vcpu, limitations

I am running an ESXi Vsphere Client Version 6.0.0 but with all the different documentation and changes I have trouble to understand my limitations.
From the [official documentation](http://www.vmware.com/ap/products/vsphere-hypervisor/gettingstarted) I see that my limit for physical CPU should be unlimited but I can only give a VM up to 8 vCPU.

From other sources I read that I have a limit of 2 physical CPU in the free version.
I see that the memory limitation is gone, which I am happy about.

Is there any document or anything which gives me actual limitations? It seems that VMware is hiding it a bit ;) , at least I coudln't use google efficently to gather the correct info here.

I am only interested in the Hardware limitations, not the limits for creating failovers etc.

Comment: This is a good overview I guess [Expired features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXKv6.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those two stats you mention are different; it's 8 virtualised CPUs per VM and 2 physical CPU sockets that they're talking about - not the same thing. BTW if you're going with the free version have a look at [THIS](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client) great new ESXi add-in that gives you a vCenter-like interface into your host via a web client - it's really new and really useful :)

Comment: hey chopper, yes I know the difference between vCPU and sockets. I just need to know if the limit for physical cpu is really 2 or higher? meaning can I use 3 sockets in the free version? with 8 vCPU per machine I am happy.

Comment: The c# client is way better than vcenter's web interface, why anyone would want to force a web client on the standalone esxi and get the worst of both worlds is mystifying.

Comment: @JamesRyan Because that's what VMware is forcing on us.

Comment: First of all the 6.0u1 web client is WAY faster and more capable than the .net client, plus of course it works without Windows, that web client is a free thing they've just done to give people (mostly the ones not paying them a penny of course) something they didn't have. That said start saying goodbye to the .net client, it's going VERY soon.

Comment: vSphere thick-client (C# client) is still here in 2017, lol.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 erm...no, it's not in 6.5, launched in 2016

Comment: Oh ok, I still just use 6.0 so didn't know that. Hopefully it's all it's cracked up to be because I can't use it in 6.0 due to the latency.

Comment: The 6.5 web UI over high latency links is basically unusable. I'm in a VSAT business where low latency isn't an option. Its actually easier to log into a Windows desktop VM that is at the remote location and use that desktop to manage ESXI 6.5 via web UI

Answer (score 14):

#### Free version Hypervisor (Esxi) Version 6.0

- 2 (physical) CPU limit
- No Ram limit (removed since 5.5)

#### Hypervisor Spec

- Number of cores per physical CPU: No limit
- Number of physical CPUs per host: No limit
- Number of logical CPUs per host: 480
- Maximum vCPUs per virtual machine: 8

http://www.vmware.com/ap/products/vsphere-hypervisor/gettingstarted.html

Comment: yes but what happened to the 2 (physical) CPU limit in version 6 ? Is it removed or still there?

Comment: nop only the ram :P

Comment: It is hard to find the official post, but on an installed Esxi in the Summary tab the CPU limit is wrote

Comment: The ram limit was removed in 5.5 too

Comment: Yup i just read it, it is VMware who announced it for each version after 5.1. Post has been edited to be more revealent.

Comment: Where can I find details on the Maximum vCPUs per VM for the various license levels?

Answer (score 4):

When you apply the ESXi 6 free license, it appears :

```
Product : VMware vSphere Hypervisor Licenced 6 for 2 physical CPUs ( unlimited cores per CPU)

Product features:

Up to 8 -way virtual SMP
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/03/vmware-esxi-gratuito-limitaciones.html